# How to install tomcat as unprivileged user without home directory?

Tags: linux, tomcat, chef-infra

This is the code I'm using for chef to create a group tomcat in a vm and then a user tomcat but i would like for tomcat to be an unprivileged user and not have a home directory.

I see it has a home directory when i run the command "cat /etc/passwd"

```
execute "groupadd tomcat" do
end

execute "sudo useradd tomcat -g tomcat -m -s /bin/bash" do
end
```

Is there something i need to add or take away from this?

Comment: Why are you using execute resources? Chef has built-in `user` and `group` resources. This is not idemptotent.

Comment: This question does not demonstrate minimal understanding of the topic at hand.

Comment: Why not use the standard tomcat cookbook? See: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat